# MySQL returns the name of the column instead of the value

Tags: python, mysql

I am reading from MySQL database to find the value of specific columns in the database using the following command:

```
select = ["c9", "TEMP"]
c.execute("SELECT Client, %s, Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'", (select[1],select[0]))
```

But instead I am getting the values below, which are correct for the first and the third columns, however, I am getting the name of the second column instead of the value:

```
('c9', 'TEMP', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 6, 53))
('c9', 'TEMP', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 7, 53))
('c9', 'TEMP', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 8, 53))
```

instead of this for example

```
('c9', '2700', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 6, 53))
('c9', '2720', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 7, 53))
('c9', '2700', datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 26, 20, 8, 53))
```

So, how do I retrieve the value instead of the name of the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names can't be parameterized in the query.  You'll have to insert the column name some other way:

```
select = ["c9", "TEMP"]
query = "SELECT Client, {}, Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'".format(select[1])
cursor.execute(query, (select[0],))
```

Note that this leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection where you insert the column name.  You'll want to check it to make sure that it's safe.  I'd err on the side of caution and do something like:

```
assert select[1].isalnum()
```

<sup><sup>(`AssertionError` probably isn't the right error here since it should be used to check internal invariants.  Raising a `ValueError` or custom exception *might* be more appropriate).</sup></sup>

Comment: Thank you boss. This worked for me, but I wanted to ask about the security issue, why not use this command `c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'".format(select[1]), select[0])`? I would have used it except that it does give me this error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: I think it's because the parameters need to be provided as a [sequence or a mapping](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14).  You're passing `select[0]` which is a string (a sequence of characters).    Does it work if you do: `c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'".format(select[1]), [select[0]])`?

Comment: It beautifully does, boss. Should I stick with this one? If it's better then it will be nice if you could include it in the answer.

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad -- I prefer the version where it's broken out more (I think it's easier to read and easier to write the code to validate the table name), but if you like the 1-liner, feel free to use it.